# End Javascript script after the code run 1000 times

Tags: javascript, console

**I'd like to know how can I stop Javascript script after it run 1000 times.** Any suggestions appreciated.

Here's my code:

```js
function run(){
  var first = document.querySelector(".stats-label");
  var next = document.querySelector(".shot-nav-next");

function simulateClick (elem) {
  var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    view: window 
  });
  var canceled = !elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
  };

  if (first-pic.innerHTML == "View"){
    simulateClick(first);
    simulateClick(next);
  }
  else {
    simulateClick(next);
  }
}

setInterval((run),20000);

void 0;
```

Comment: add a counter to your code

Answer (score 2):

something like this ?

```js
var counter = 0;

function run(){
  var first = document.querySelector(".stats-label");
  var next = document.querySelector(".shot-nav-next");
      

  if(counter < 1000){
    if (first-pic.innerHTML == "View"){
      simulateClick(first);
      simulateClick(next);
    }
    else {
       simulateClick(next);
    }
   }
   counter++;
}


function simulateClick (elem) {
   var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
      view: window 
    });
    var canceled = !elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
 };

 setInterval((run),20000);
```

Comment: Did you mean to move the `setInterval` inside the `simulateClick` function body? That would have a pretty nasty side result...

Comment: @FissureKing No, Indentation whas a bit wierd. fixed it now.